# Anonymous users with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If I want to build a chatroom with rails (canonical case) with a choice of anonymous ('pick a nickname') and authorized (u/n & pw), how would I build this with Devise?

I've successfully got Devise working in the latter case, it's the anonymous part (create & maintain a session) I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use extra before_filter to setup anonymous user, for instance,

```
def anonymous_sign_in
  return if user_signed_in?
  u = User.new(:type => 'anonymous')
  u.save(:validate => false)
  sign_in :user, u
end
```

Comment: how do you guarantee this gets called AFTER the devise sign_in method?

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a Devise Wiki page for that, only they call it Guest user:

[How To: Create a guest user](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is not to sign in a guest user, but have current_user return a guest user in the absence of a signed in user.

In the below if the user is not signed in then `current_user` will return a guest user. So any controller which can be access without signing in do not need the `authenticate_user!` before filter.

```
def current_user                                                              
  super || guest_user                                                         
end                                                                           

def guest_user                                                                
  User.find(session[:guest_user_id].nil? ? session[:guest_user_id] = create_guest_user.id : session[:guest_user_id])
end                                                                           

def create_guest_user                                                         
  token = SecureRandom.base64(15)                                             
  user = User.new(:first_name => "anonymous", :last_name => 'user', :password => token, :email => "#{token@example.com}")
  user.save(:validate => false)                                               
  user                                                                        
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#user.rb
    # Creates an anonymous user. An anonymous user is basically an auto-generated
    # +User+ account that is created for the customer behind the scenes and its
    # completely transparently to the customer.
    def anonymous!(nickname)
      temp_token = SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=', 'xyz')
      usr = ::User.new(email: "#{temp_token}@example.net", password: temp_token, password_confirmation: temp_token, nickname: nickname)
      usr.save!(validate: false)
      usr
    end
```

You can then delete the record when it suits.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in Rails 6:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :anonymous_sign_in

  def anonymous_sign_in
    return if user_signed_in?

    u = User.new(:name => 'anonymous')
    u.save(:validate => false)
    sign_in :user, u
  end
end
```

From the default devise generated model, I've removed the email default and null constraint, and added the name:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :name

      ## Database authenticatable
      # t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      # ...
```